# AngularFire2 error "ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to create a user with email/password using AngularFire2

this is the code that is throwing the error when i click the submit button in my signup component:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.value.email, this.signupForm.value.password).catch(function(error) {
  alert(error.message);
});
```

versions from package.json:

```
angular: "^2.3.1",
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
"firebase": "^3.6.6"
```

I've been having trouble implementing email/pass auth with angularfire2 from the start, and I've searched for over an hour and a half looking for answers to this problem (among others, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of info/support for angularfire2 yet?)

please help!
I'm still learning, and this truly has me stumped.

here is the full error in the console:

```
vendor.bundle.js:46373 ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
at SignupComponent.webpackJsonp.806.SignupComponent.signup        (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:601:9)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_SignupComponent0.handleEvent_0 (/AppModule/SignupComponent/component.ngfactory.js:152:34)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65473:37)
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79924:36)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:52413:16)
at SafeSubscriber.next  (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:52362:22)
at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:52315:26)
at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:52279:18)
at EventEmitter.Subject.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:52079:25)
at EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79898:76)
at FormGroupDirective.onSubmit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:81620:23)
at Wrapper_FormGroupDirective.handleEvent (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormGroupDirective/wrapper.ngfactory.js:42:34)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_SignupComponent0.handleEvent_0 (/AppModule/SignupComponent/component.ngfactory.js:150:42)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65473:37)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34579:53)
```

Comment: Please post also the error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AngulareFire to create user with email/password something likes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
@Component({
        ...
    })
export class MyApp {
    constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.createUser({ email: email, password: password})
        .then ((user) => {
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {        
            console.log(error);
            });

    }
}
```

If you want to use firebase, then try to declare variable `firebase` right below your import section: 
`var firebase = require("firebase"); // <-- Declare firebase variable here`

It is in my working component. Let's me know about the result.

Comment: yes, I've added an answer that explains how i got it to work and what the problem ended up being

Answer (score 2):

So, what turned out to be the problem was as follows:

I ended up revising **this** block of code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.value.email, this.signupForm.value.password).catch(function(error) {                    
  alert(error.message);
});
```

to **this**:

```
this.af.auth.createUser(this.signupForm.value).catch(function(error) {
  alert(error.message);
});
```

the problem was in the fact that i was calling upon the wrong object, `firebase`, when I **should have** been calling upon `this.af.auth` as i had defined `public af: AngularFire` in my constructor.

**there was also another error**, and that was the fact that i was calling the wrong **method** on the angularfire2 module:

I used

`.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)`

when i should've been using

`.createUser({email, password})`

fixing these two issues made the application work as expected with no errors.

***@sugarme*** was the correct answer I just happened to come to the same conclusion right before i left school so i did not have time to post this answer until now.

Thanks all!

PS Here is my full `signup.component` for reference:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent {

  public signupForm = this.fb.group({
    email: [""],
    password: [""]
  });
  constructor(private router: Router, public fb: FormBuilder, public af: AngularFire) {}
  signup() {
    console.log(this.signupForm.value);
    this.af.auth.createUser(this.signupForm.value).catch(function(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    });
    this.router.navigate(['store'])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install firebase?

```
npm install firebase --save
```

I know it's a dependency of angularfire2 package. But your script did not find it.

May you have an know and solved issue:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/520

Comment: 1. yes i have firebase installed, i just reinstalled just to triple check, same error. 
2. I have already looked at that issue and it did not solve mine.
3. Google auth with firebase worked just fine earlier, using the command `af.auth.login();` but you do not use the `firebase` global for that command

Answer (score 0):

properly you missed to import firebase into the page

```
import { FirebaseProvider } from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase';
```